# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$blank in drupal_alter() (line 1080 of /home/esundance/public_html/bracken-umc.org/includes/module.inc)

Tags: migrations, theming

I'm new to this and am not familiar with coding, so I need some major help. I am transferring this site from MonsterWeb server to a GoDaddy server.

While it was still on MonsterWeb servers:
I downloaded all of the website files.
I exported the SQL database.

I followed GoDaddy's instruction and:
Created the database.
I imported the SQL database.
I created the domain and document root in the File Manager.
I uploaded the website files to the root directory.
I installed the Drupal Application and made sure it was pointed to the correct database and root directory.

When I went to the admin page of the site, I received multiple errors, see [image: screenshot].

I don't know what to do from here, and I don't know what code to change, etc.